# MongoDB: add field with conditional number of elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have next simplified collection

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "array": [
      {        "check": true      },
      {        "check": false      },
      {        "check": true      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 2
  }
]
```

I want to add field "count" with number of elements of array with "check"=true, so I expect next result

```
  {
    "key": 1,
    "array": [
      {        "check": true      },
      {        "check": false      },
      {        "check": true      }
    ],
    "count":2,
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

I have next query ( it is aggregation, because actually it one of stages of pipeline)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "count": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": ["$array.check",true],              
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0,            
          }
        }
      },      
    }
  }
])
```

But I always get count=0.

Can you help me to find error in my query?

Here [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KwiXSeeeEbL)

Comment: You can use the [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) aggregation array operator to calculate the conditional count.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Possibly $reduce is the best solution.

I also try to understand, why my query is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$sum`, you can use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter only the array with `"check"=true`, then check the size of the resulting array using [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "count": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$ifNull": ["$array", []] }, // default empty array if array is does not exist
            "cond": "$$this.check" // only keep the truthy check value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oIznlvRX-vO)

Alternatively, if you want to use `$sum`, you could also map the array to an array of 0 and 1 according to the `check` value, using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "count": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": { "$ifNull": ["$array", []] },
            "in": {
              "$cond": ["$$this.check", 1, 0]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aeqs0jZihZF)

Comment: Yes, it is possible solution, thanks. 
But I also try to understand, why sum with cond is not working.

Comment: Because you are using *not* using `$sum` in the `$group` stage. Your use of `$sum` accept and array expression and calculate the sum of the values in the array. You can not put conditional logic there.

Comment: You can do the aggregation with `$unwind` and then group with sum _conditionally_.

Comment: @Ragnar I have added an alternative using `$sum` with `$map`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to achieve this using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "count": {
        "$sum": {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$array",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: {
              $sum: [
                "$$value",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    "$$this.check",
                    1,
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4MFByBAhnjA)

Answer (score 0):

Using `$reduce` aggregation array expression operator,

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          count: { 
              $reduce: { 
                  input: { $ifNull: [ "$array", [] ] }, 
                  initialValue: 0, 
                  in: { 
                      $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.check", true ] }, 
                               { $add: [ "$$value", 1 ] }, 
                               "$$value" 
                      ] 
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
] )
```

gets a result as follows:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c7b691c7c98bb49fd2b50"),
        "key" : 1,
        "array" : [
                {
                        "check" : true
                },
                {
                        "check" : false
                },
                {
                        "check" : true
                }
        ],
        "count" : 2
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f0c7b691c7c98bb49fd2b51"), "key" : 2, "count" : 0 }
```